# Insert boilerplate methods code when adding protocols to classes?

Tags: xcode, swift, ide

Is it possible to somehow get default required methods when I add some protocol to a class in XCode?

For example, I want to make `Person` class conform to the `NSCoding` protocol, so I want `required convenience init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder){}` and `func encoderWithCoder(aCoder: NSCoder){}` to be inserted:

```
class Person: NSObject, NSCoding {
    // Add required methods automatically
}
```

Are there plugins or default functionality I didn't find?

Comment: Many people are looking for something like this. Hopefully it will be added in Xcode 8.